# How to node js export multiple functions

Tags: node.js, backend

I am trying to export common methods in a common js file. but it was exported only to the last method. how to fix it?

common.js

```
module.export = getMethodOne = async ()=>{}
module.export = getMethodTwo= async ()=>{}
```

main.js

```
var getMethodOne = require("./common.js");
var getMethodTwo = require("./common.js");
```

I will try this way. but it was not working.

```
module.export = {
  getMethodOne = async ()=>{}
  getMethodTwo= async ()=>{}
}
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Common.js

```
getMethodOne = async ()=>{};
getMethodTwo= async ()=>{};
module.exports = { getMethodOne, getMethodTwo };
```

Main.js

```
const { getMethodOne, getMethodTwo } = require('./common');
```